# step function measurable proof

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $I:=[a,b], a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b$. Define $B_{I}:=B(\mathbb{R})|_{I}$ i.e. the Boreal sets of the reals restricted to the interval. Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a step function.

Show that $f:(I,B_{I}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ i.e. the function is $I$-$B(\mathbb{R})$ measurable.

Attempt: By definition we say that a function is $A$-$B$ measurable if $f^{-1}(A) \in A_{1}, \forall A \in A_{2}$ where $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ denote sigma algebras.

So I need to show that for any $A \in B(\mathbb{R}), f^{-1}(A) \in \ B_{I}$. Let $A \in B(\mathbb{R})$ then $f^{-1}(A)=\{x \in I: f(x) \in A\}$

How do I evaluate what this set is equal to?

Comment: I would first reduce the problem to showing $\{x \in I \mid f(x) >t\}$ is measurable for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: A step function is a linear combination of indicators of intervals. Since intervals are measurable, the step function is too.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, that's because its an equivalent form of measurability? I'm still not too sure how to proceed though since the constants for the step function can be anything for each interval in the decomposition.  If I take $x_{i} \in I$ then $f(x_{1})=k_{1}$ say for some constant $k_{1}$ but then $f(x_{2}) $ doesn't have to equal $k_{1}$?

Comment: Take an example of a step function with $3$ values.  Then compute $\{x \mid f(x) > t\}$ for all $t$.  Maybe doing such an example will suggest how to do it in general.

Comment: @GEdgar on a phone so excuse formatting. I’ve taken a simple example: $I=[0,1]$ with $f(x)= 0.5 for x \in [0,0.5)$ $1$ for $x \in [0.5,0.75)$ and $2$ for $x\in [0.75,1]$. Graphing this it seems that if I take any $x \in I$ i’m never going to have the image greater than $t$ for all $t$ so I would have to take the complement of those points? $(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$? 

My only issue with this is these are defined in the definition of $I$?

Comment: In your example: $\{x : f(x)>t\}=\varnothing$ if $t > 2$; and $\{x : f(x)>t\} = [0.75,1]$ if $1<t\le 2$; and $\{x : f(x)>t\}=[0.5,1]$ if $0<t\le 1$; and  $\{x : f(x)>t\}=[0,1]$ if $t \le 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Ah I see! That makes sense. I can see how to do it in general now, thanks.